# I want to redirect to another mux handler within a handler in golang server side

Tags: go

I am very new in golang.
I am trying to redirect my handler to another handler when a specific case is met. I am trying to basically redirect from one page to another in golang. When the user data is processed and met within the database then should redirect to another route. But when i try to redirect in to the other place, i get this error:

```
http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from main.Second.ServeHTTP
```

Please someone help me.

Here is my backend code for the redirection.

```
type Second int

func (m Second) ServeHTTP(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    
    

    //to execute the html file
    var temp *template.Template
    temp = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("Secondpage login.html"))
    err := temp.ExecuteTemplate(res, "Secondpage login.html", 32)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)

//this part here is giving me error and headache
            http.Redirect(res, req, "/error404/", http.StatusSeeOther)
            fmt.Println("here we redirecting")
```

here is that /error/ code

```
func (m Fifth) ServeHTTP(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("we are in error page ")
    var temp *template.Template
    temp = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("Fifth Error.html"))
    err := temp.ExecuteTemplate(res, "Fifth Error.html", 1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}
```

here is the error html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>ERROR:404</h1>
    <h3>Something went wrong</h3>
    <h3>Redirecting back you to home page</h3>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you returning from the handler after the `http.Redirect()` call? It looks you don't and subsequent code also tries to write headers.

Comment: http.Redirect writes an HTTP header (and possibly a body, see docs). Writing a header is impossible after writing the body -- done by executing the template --, because the header must precede the body. You have to call Redirect before writing anything to the ResponseWriter.

Comment: @Peter so how can i redirect to another handler if an specific case is met. The thing i am doing is showing a form and after taking value from that form and checking it in the database, if the details are correct then proceed else redirect to error404 handler which execute a error page. How can i achieve this goal ?